# Save the output of azure's multi-variate anomaly detection

Tags: python, pandas, azure, csv, anomaly-detection

I was trying azure's multi- variate anomaly detection. I printed output like this,
[image: I print output like this]. Using,

```
for r in result.results:
    print(f"timestamp: {r.timestamp}, is anomaly: {r.value.is_anomaly}, scores: {r.value.score}, severities: {r.value.severity}, contributors: {r.value.contributors}")
```

But I want to save it as a .csv file like this

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|timestamp          | is anomaly|severity|score|contributors |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|2021, 1, 2, 12, 0  | False     |  0.33  | 0.0 |   None      |
|2021, 1, 2, 12, 1  | True      |  1.7   |   1 |   None      |
|2021, 1, 2, 12, 3  | False     |  0.98  | 0.0 |   None      |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
print(f"timestamp,is anomaly,scores,severities,contributors")
for r in result.results:
    print(",".join(str(val) for val in [r.timestamp, r.value.is_anomaly, r.value.score, r.value.severity, r.value.contributors]))
```